# Some way to make Facebook Single Sign-On (SSO) work for Android browsers?

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

as I know Facebook Single Sign On works only if Facebook app has been installed on the device. But if there a way to make it recognize Android browsers sessions to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's not possible since even Facebook app doesn't share session with its site.

Answer (score 0):

for that, i think our app needs to have access to the browser cookies and it needs to know the cookie key-value pairs(access_token,if any) set by facebook during the browsing sessions in the browser. I'm not sure as to whether is it really possible or not, but i guess thats one possible method.